# Why these errors are not automagically converted to my custom error even if they are implementing both std::error::Error trait?

Tags: rust, error-handling

Reproduction project (single main.rs file): https://github.com/frederikhors/iss-custom-err.

I'm trying to create a custom error for my app:

```rust
pub struct AppError {
    message: String,
    error: anyhow::Error, // In the future I would also avoid anyhow
}
```

I'm trying to use it in my code but as you can see I'm getting the below compiler errors, why?

**Isn't my `AppError` implementing the trait `std::error::Error` correctly?**

I would expect an auto conversion from `hyper` error to `AppError` being both error:Error traits, am I wrong?

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `AppError`
  --> src\main.rs:20:44
   |
20 |                     .body(Body::from(body))?;
   |                                            ^ the trait `From<hyper::http::Error>` is not implemented for `AppError`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `FromResidual<R>`:
             <Result<T, F> as FromResidual<Result<Infallible, E>>>
             <Result<T, F> as FromResidual<Yeet<E>>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, hyper::http::Error>>` for `Result<(), AppError>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `AppError`
  --> src\main.rs:24:19
   |
24 |             .await?;
   |                   ^ the trait `From<hyper::Error>` is not implemented for `AppError`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `FromResidual<R>`:
             <Result<T, F> as FromResidual<Result<Infallible, E>>>
             <Result<T, F> as FromResidual<Yeet<E>>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, hyper::Error>>` for `Result<(), AppError>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would expect an auto conversion from hyper error to AppError being both error:Error traits, am I wrong?

Yes. `Error` is a *usage* trait, it's like `IntoIterator`: both `Vec` and `HashMap` implement it, but that doesn't mean you can convert an arbitrary `Vec` to a `HashMap`.

Let alone that Rust will do it for you: Rust generally favors intentionality, it avoids large multi-use concepts. So all `error` tells you is that you can display the type, and may be able to get its `source`. It says nothing about conversion, except for conversion to a `Box<dyn Error>` (because `Error` is object-safe).

So *as the compiler error tells you*, if you want Rust (and specifically `?`) to perform the conversion, you need to implement [the `From` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html).

Note: libraries like [`thiserror`](https://docs.rs/thiserror/latest/thiserror/) or [`snafu`](https://docs.rs/snafu/latest/snafu/index.html) provide tooling to more easily create bespoke error types, and conversions from existing error types.

Answer (score 0):

On discord a kind user helped me understand.

What I need is a generic `impl`:

```rust
impl<T: error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static> From<T> for AppError {
    fn from(e: T) -> Self {
        Self { message: e.to_string(), error: anyhow::Error::new(e) }
    }
}
```

That's it!

Comment: that's certainly one way to solve it! What is missing here is that, in practice, you probably want your AppError to be descriptive / custom for the types of failures that your app has. Errors can provide that context, instead of just passing thru the message